# main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor" [] []

Tags: magento2

I add a custom module , it has a backend manager,when i add a menu in backend,302 errors
**menu.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magezoom_Adminmenu::adminmenu" module="Magezoom_Adminmenu" title="Magezoom" translate="title"  sortOrder="999"  resource="Magezoom_Adminmenu::adminmenu"/>
        <add id="Magezoom_Navigation::setting" title="Design" translate="title" module="Magezoom_Navigation" sortOrder="20" parent="Magezoom_Adminmenu::adminmenu" resource="Magezoom_Adminmenu::adminmenu"/>
        <add id="Magezoom_Navigation::navigation" title="Navigation" translate="title" module="Magezoom_Navigation" sortOrder="20" parent="Magezoom_Navigation::setting" resource="Magezoom_Adminmenu::adminmenu"  action="adminhtml/navigation" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

**routes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="navigation" frontName="navigation">
            <module name="Magezoom_Navigation" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

controller **Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Magezoom\Navigation\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

  class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
  {
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Load the page defined in view/adminhtml/layout/exampleadminnewpage_helloworld_index.xml
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
         return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
  }
?>
```

**debug.log**

about 10 times

```
main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor" [] []
```

url become this:

```
http://magento-dev.com/admin/admin/navigation/index/key/a94a1b0e9c7dfd64a3f6cf422d5381deac7111115166375a4107dbd10c71c773/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/adminhtml/dashboard
```

Comment: In that case You should have more errors in your php logs. Maybe in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: There is no error in apache error log file

Comment: What if  you un-comment the line ini_set in app/bootstrap.php

Comment: It's already un-commented

Answer (score 6):

First things first, controller action should extend `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` class and implement `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Http<method>ActionInterface` where  is one of HTTP Request methods.
Magento uses `Magento\Framework\App\Request\CompositeValidator` to validate requests, on validation error you get `Request validation failed for action ...`

To address your issue you need to pinpoint validator that failed. In my case (with was a POST controller retrieving a data from another service) my request lacked a param isAjax = true, when I added this param to the URL (like so: `http://127.0.0.1/<my_route>?isAjax=true`) it solved my problem. In your case, it might be another validator so the solution is not universal.

Validators that take part in validating POST requests are:

[Magento\Framework\App\Request\CsrfValidator](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Request/CsrfValidator.php)
and
[Magento\Framework\App\Request\HttpMethodValidator](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php)

Summarising:

```
class <MethodName> extends Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface
{
    public function execute(): \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
    {
        return $this->resultFactory->create();
    }
}
```

and the url: `http://127.0.0.1/<my_route>?isAjax=true` request method POST

Comment: How to pinpoint which validator failing

Answer (score 1):

Issue may also happen if admin router front name is used in getUrl instead of router id as security parameter 'key' is generated based on the route path. Magento front controller matches corresponding router and action and then it uses router ID and controller action name. It newer uses router front name. Front name is used in URLs in FE just to make them more readable, shorter, laconic, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<?php

namespace Magezoom\Navigation\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{          
    public function execute()
    {
         return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    }
}
```

And in your menu, change the value of **`resource`**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magezoom_Adminmenu::adminmenu" module="Magezoom_Adminmenu" title="Magezoom" translate="title"  sortOrder="999"  resource="Magezoom_Adminmenu::adminmenu"/>
        <add id="Magezoom_Navigation::setting" title="Design" translate="title" module="Magezoom_Navigation" sortOrder="20" parent="Magezoom_Adminmenu::adminmenu" resource="Magezoom_Navigation::setting"/>
        <add id="Magezoom_Navigation::navigation" title="Navigation" translate="title" module="Magezoom_Navigation" sortOrder="20" parent="Magezoom_Navigation::setting" resource="Magezoom_Navigation::navigation"  action="adminhtml/navigation" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

If action doesn't work correctly, you can try like : **`action="navigation"`**

Comment: Does it need clean cache?Which cache should be cleaned?

Comment: have you tried my answer? after applying changes above, run upgrade, di:compile then redeploy static contents. it should work

Comment: not working after un upgrade, di:compile and redeploy static contents

Comment: the url changes, is that after you apply the changes in the code?

Comment: tow kinds of url both 302

Comment: maybe i will try later in my pc. but did you apply the changes I made in menu.xml?

Comment: yes i did.And I found the cause of the error is `$secretKeyValue` is empty string , `$secretKeyValue` is in `Magento\\Backend\\App\\Request\\BackendValidator` class.But i don't thown why.

Comment: `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` `getParam()` method returned an empty string, because `Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request` `$params[]` is an empty array, i don't kown why it's empty

Comment: I solved this problem finaly, controller namespace was wrong

Comment: That's great :)

Comment: In my case I for Magento 2.4 was implementing the wrong interface before I implements `Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface` but it should be `Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface`.Now I am getting the error when controller call 'Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.'

Comment: Now I am getting the error when controller call 'Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page. And it is magento core issue which is explained at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/346695/magento-2-4-3-admin-dashboard-invalid-security-or-form-key-please-refresh-the

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the form_key. I've added form key input field explicitly in  and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check for typos in the controller's class name, or the filename etc. You might have a lowercase 's' when you need a capital 'S', for example.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is from data you had input.
If there's no other logs written by Magento system, I think the problem is from your server system. You need to go to server error log to detect it. In this case, I think it's the size limit of variable (upload files size) in your PHP config.