# Magento 2.4.3 admin dashboard - Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4, dashboard, magento2.4.3

After upgrading to Magento 2.4.3 Community Edition I am getting `Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.` on the admin dashboard site after logging in.

Reloading the page makes the error disappear.

Things I tried so far without any luck:

- increasing `max_input_vars`
- making sure file permissions are correct
- testing setting `max_session_size_admin` to `0` and `512000`
- disabled all third party modules
- recompiling, setup:upgrade, removing static, generated files and so on

I don't know if this is a Magento 2.4.3 bug or faulty server configuration or if something in my database is broken.

Comment: have you tryed clearing var/session and var/cache ?

Comment: This fix is also added to Magento Quality Patches Tool (QPT)  MDVA-40311 See https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/blob/master/patches/os/MDVA-40311_2.4.2-p2.patch and https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4415260784141-MDVA-40311-Invalid-security-or-form-key-error-after-login-into-Admin-if-custom-admin-path-is-configured

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a new bug when using another URL than `admin`.

You need to make changes to the following file:

`\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php`

See the code changes over at
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33749#issuecomment-908145941

This issue will be resolved in 2.4.4.

Comment: This file doesn't even exist in 2.4.3-p1
Any tipes?
File: \vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php

Comment: Yes , you saved my day

Answer (score 10):

For those who use composer to patch to save you all some time

`composer require cweagans/composer-patches`

`./patches/composer/invalid.key.patch`

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php b/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php
index 8227966..cc32c36 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php
@@ -225,10 +225,9 @@ class Authentication
 
         // Checks, whether secret key is required for admin access or request uri is explicitly set
         if ($this->_url->useSecretKey()) {
-            $requestParts = explode('/', trim($request->getRequestUri(), '/'), 3);
-            $baseUrlPath = trim(parse_url($this->backendUrl->getBaseUrl(), PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
-            $routeIndex = empty($baseUrlPath) ? 0 : 1;
-            $requestUri = $this->_url->getUrl($requestParts[$routeIndex]);
+            // The requested URL has an invalid secret key and therefore redirecting to this URL
+            // will cause a security vulnerability.
+            $requestUri = $this->_url->getUrl($this->_url->getStartupPageUrl());
         } elseif ($request) {
             $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();
         }
```

`composer.json`

```
"extra": {
        "magento-force": "override",
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
        "patches": {
            "magento/module-backend": {
                "Invalid key error": "patches/composer/invalid.key.patch"
            }
        }
    }
```

Then run

`composer install`

Comment: Yes, I would also recommend this answer

Comment: Thanks for posting the patch. Works perfect on 2.4.3-p2

Answer (score 5):

Since the Magento 2.4.4 update will be released at March 2022 it make sense to create a little bugfix module, here is the code:

Create a basic module nutshell:
Vendor_InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix',
    __DIR__
);
```

Adding a sequence for loading our module after the Magento_Backend module
Vendor_InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Vendor_InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix/composer.json

```
{
  "name": "vendor/invalid-security-form-key-bug-fix",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "description": "This Module is a bug fix for the error message in the dashboard after login into the backend",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.3.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Now adding a di preference for overriding the Authentication.php with our AuthenticationOverride.php
Vendor_InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication" type="Vendor\InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix\App\Action\Plugin\AuthenticationOverride" />
</config>
```

And finally the replacement of the method _redirectIfNeededAfterLogin from the github issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33749#issuecomment-908145941 of the above comment.
Vendor_InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix/App/Action/Plugin/AuthenticationOverride.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\InvalidSecurityFormKeyBugFix\App\Action\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class AuthenticationOverride
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth
     */
    protected $_auth;

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $_openActions = [
        'forgotpassword',
        'resetpassword',
        'resetpasswordpost',
        'logout',
        'refresh', // captcha refresh
    ];

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     */
    protected $_response;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag
     */
    protected $_actionFlag;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     */
    protected $messageManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $backendUrl;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\App\BackendAppList
     */
    protected $backendAppList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator
     */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth $auth
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\BackendAppList $backendAppList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth $auth,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Backend\App\BackendAppList $backendAppList,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator $formKeyValidator
    ) {
        $this->_auth = $auth;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_actionFlag = $actionFlag;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->backendUrl = $backendUrl;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->backendAppList = $backendAppList;
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return mixed
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundDispatch(
        \Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $requestedActionName = $request->getActionName();
        if (in_array($requestedActionName, $this->_openActions)) {
            $request->setDispatched(true);
        } else {
            if ($this->_auth->getUser()) {
                $this->_auth->getUser()->reload();
            }
            if (!$this->_auth->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_processNotLoggedInUser($request);
            } else {
                $this->_auth->getAuthStorage()->prolong();

                $backendApp = null;
                if ($request->getParam('app')) {
                    $backendApp = $this->backendAppList->getCurrentApp();
                }

                if ($backendApp) {
                    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                    $baseUrl = \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http::getUrlNoScript($this->backendUrl->getBaseUrl());
                    $baseUrl = $baseUrl . $backendApp->getStartupPage();
                    return $resultRedirect->setUrl($baseUrl);
                }
            }
        }
        $this->_auth->getAuthStorage()->refreshAcl();
        return $proceed($request);
    }

    /**
     * Process not logged in user data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _processNotLoggedInUser(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $isRedirectNeeded = false;
        if ($request->getPost('login')) {
            if ($this->formKeyValidator->validate($request)) {
                if ($this->_performLogin($request)) {
                    $isRedirectNeeded = $this->_redirectIfNeededAfterLogin($request);
                }
            } else {
                $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                $this->_response->setRedirect($this->_url->getCurrentUrl());
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.'));
                $isRedirectNeeded = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$isRedirectNeeded && !$request->isForwarded()) {
            if ($request->getParam('isIframe')) {
                $request->setForwarded(true)
                    ->setRouteName('adminhtml')
                    ->setControllerName('auth')
                    ->setActionName('deniedIframe')
                    ->setDispatched(false);
            } elseif ($request->getParam('isAjax')) {
                $request->setForwarded(true)
                    ->setRouteName('adminhtml')
                    ->setControllerName('auth')
                    ->setActionName('deniedJson')
                    ->setDispatched(false);
            } else {
                $request->setForwarded(true)
                    ->setRouteName('adminhtml')
                    ->setControllerName('auth')
                    ->setActionName('login')
                    ->setDispatched(false);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs login, if user submitted login form
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _performLogin(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $outputValue = true;
        $postLogin = $request->getPost('login');
        $username = isset($postLogin['username']) ? $postLogin['username'] : '';
        $password = isset($postLogin['password']) ? $postLogin['password'] : '';
        $request->setPostValue('login', null);

        try {
            $this->_auth->login($username, $password);
        } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
            if (!$request->getParam('messageSent')) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                $request->setParam('messageSent', true);
                $outputValue = false;
            }
        }
        return $outputValue;
    }

    /**
     * Checks, whether Magento requires redirection after successful admin login, and redirects user, if needed
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _redirectIfNeededAfterLogin(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $requestUri = null;

        // Checks, whether secret key is required for admin access or request uri is explicitly set
        if ($this->_url->useSecretKey()) {
            $requestParts = strpos(trim($request->getRequestUri(),'/'), $request->getFrontName()) === 0 ?
                explode('/', trim($request->getRequestUri(), '/'), 4) :
                explode('/', trim($request->getRequestUri(), '/'), 3);
            if (($key = array_search($request->getFrontName(), $requestParts)) !== false) {
                unset($requestParts[$key]);
            }
            $requestParams = $request->getParams();
            unset($requestParams['key'], $requestParams['form_key']);
            $requestUri = $this->_url->getUrl(implode('/', $requestParts), $requestParams);
        } elseif ($request) {
            $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();
        }

        if (!$requestUri) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->_response->setRedirect($requestUri);
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Install the module and register it in DB

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Now, the error message should not come anymore after login in the backend
Hope this helps and do not forget to remove the bugfix after update to Magento 2.4.4 :-)

Comment: Instead of overwriting the complete `Authentication` class I would always prefer to extend from the Magento Authentication class and overwrite only the `_redirectIfNeededAfterLogin` method.

Answer (score 4):

This fix is also added to Magento Quality Patches Tool (QPT)

If Magento Quality Patches Tool is not already installed then install using composer

> composer require magento/quality-patches

Apply patch MDVA-40311

> ./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply MDVA-40311

See

- https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/blob/master/patches/os/MDVA-40311_2.4.2-p2.patch
- https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4415260784141-MDVA-40311-Invalid-security-or-form-key-error-after-login-into-Admin-if-custom-admin-path-is-configured

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the patch, applied and this helped solving the problem

Answer (score 2):

That is ok to have a low limit for session size to prevent DDOS attacks, value can be changed via the admin panel if needed.
Another problem that should be addressed is - suppressed problem, without any error notification to the user and a solution for the issue should be provided.

Magento 2.4, when we log into the backend (admin panel), every page hangs/is loading for about 30 seconds.

In logs we see exceptions:
The session size of 276672 exceeded the allowed session max size of 256000.

We are using Redis for sessions.

Does anybody else have a similar issue after upgrading to Magento 2.4.3?

From redis-cli monitor we see that in each second is repeated:
1628681344.757076 [3 127.0.0.1:34310] "hincrby" "sess_1g2sgh25saul85a424puad785d" "lock" "1"

> Steps to reproduce (*)

Upgrade Magento 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3
Configured Magento to use Redis for session storage

*Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Security - Max Session Size in Admin and Max Session Size in Storefront set to 100 and Saved*
Navigate to any page from Admin -

> Actual result (*)

Page load time is increased to more than 30 sec

Comment: yes shortest solution its worked for me after set Max Session Size in Admin: 2560000

Answer (score 0):

This is a new bug when using another URL than admin.

You will need to change below file.

\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modify Authentication.php is not the perfect solution, the session will crash after logout the admin due to out of maximum session time. page will get an error code for this.

e.g no action stay at the admin session over a maximum time, click the logout button you will get an error code.

I think upgrading to Magento 2.4.4 or a higher version would be better.