# No payment methods frontend and perpetual page loading spinner after Magento 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p1 upgrade

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1

After a seemingly successful 2.4.2 -> 2.4.3-p1 adventure I get 'no payment methods' on the checkout page. Most of the time the checkout page will hang at the page loading spinner until page refresh, but sometimes this doesn't happen.

We use Opayo as our payment gateway, extension provided by Magenest, latest version. Even 'Cash on delivery' as an enabled payment method does not show on the frontend. If I rollback to 2.4.2 the payment method is available.

The only JS error in the console is:

```
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiUi/js/webapiReCaptchaRegistry
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

which from what I have read doesn't break anything.

Any ideas?

For reference, this is the contents of app/design/frontend/***/***/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getShoppingCartUrl()) ?>"
    data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12"><path d="M11.122 1.091h-8.94a.267.267 0 00-.077.018l-.22-.722A.545.545 0 001.364 0H.273A.273.273 0 000 .273v.545a.273.273 0 00.273.273H.96l1.7 5.6-.636.742A1.137 1.137 0 001.778 8.5a1.084 1.084 0 001.044.773h7.814A.273.273 0 0010.909 9v-.545a.273.273 0 00-.273-.273H2.822l.865-1.009a.541.541 0 00.054-.082h5.285a1.091 1.091 0 00.987-.627l1.9-4.044A.886.886 0 0012 2.046v-.077a.878.878 0 00-.878-.878z" /><circle cx="1.091" cy="1.091" r="1.091" transform="translate(2.182 9.818)" /><circle cx="1.091" cy="1.091" r="1.091" transform="translate(8.727 9.818)" /></svg>
        <span class="text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My Cart')) ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
            data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false && !isLoading() }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <?php /*
                <span class="counter-label">
                    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                        <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </span>
            */?>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()) :?>
        <div class="block block-minicart"
            data-role="dropdownDialog"
            data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
    <?php else :?>
        <script>
            require(['jquery'], function ($) {
                $('a.action.showcart').click(function() {
                    $(document.body).trigger('processStart');
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= $block->escapeJs(
                $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))
            ) ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

And just to confirm, this is what happens when switching to Luma theme:

[image: switching to Luma makes no difference]

**Edit:**
So I fixed the problem. For some reason during the upgrade the following plugins were disabled:
Magento_ReCaptchaStorePickup
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiApi
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiGraphQl
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiRest
Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiUi

I re-enabled them and the checkout now works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33741) with Recaptcha in magento 2.4.3 and 2.4.3-p1, not sure if your case is related to that issue or not. Due to magento 2.4.3-p3 released some months ago, and the Opayo module from Magenest compatible with magento 2.4.3, and 2.4.4, I suggest you upgrade your site to 2.4.3-p3 and check if that issue still persists.

If upgrading your site to 2.4.3-p3 does not resolve the issue, I'll continue help you to debug and fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now and report back

Comment: I upgraded Magento to 2.4.3-p3 but the problem remains, plus I now get 'Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.' on every admin page.

Comment: for the 'Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page.', you can apply one of the solutions here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/346695/magento-2-4-3-admin-dashboard-invalid-security-or-form-key-please-refresh-the
I think it will be more error lines in the console. Could you please share that?

Comment: Refreshing the page doesn't clear the message and no errors in console for admin pages, just this: loader_old.js:205 Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom
_onAjaxSend @ loader_old.js:205. Trying solutions on link

Comment: you can ignore this (invalid security) notice, this issue was fixed in magento 2.4.4. I would like to know the console on the checkout page not in the admin, sorry for making you misunderstood.

Comment: ah, sorry. I get the following error messages in the console on the checkout/#payment page: [2022-10-12 02:55:47] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiUi/js/webapiReCaptcha" component.
ConsoleOutputHandler.show @ console-output-handler.js:34
knockout.js:3753  -  Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"  -  Uncaught ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined  -  ncaught Error: Script error for: Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiUi/js/webapiReCaptchaRegistry

Comment: please check your custom theme/modules files that override core templates:  vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml and vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html
make sure your override files update the changes from core files.
after that, re-deploy static content and clear cache by: `rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f --area frontend && bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: exactly the same problem, with the addition of perpetual page load spinner (can't clear with refresh)

Comment: same behaviour when switching to Luma

Comment: did you check override's files I mentioned above?

Comment: yes, only the minicart.phtml was overridden so I updated changes etc but still same issue

Comment: could you share the minicart.phtml file content in the post, so I can check?

Comment: ah is it something to do with the data-bind?

Comment: I've checked your minicart.phtml, and it looks fine.

Comment: I think something is wrong that relates to content.html file, I would like to debug it on your computer, is it ok?

Comment: If you're happy to do that I'll love you forever! lol

Comment: here is the link to chat.stackexchange.com https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139843/discussion-between-tu-van-and-eleventy-about-error-on-frontend-after-upgrade-mage